# Apply mutually_exclusive_group in Jupyter magic custom function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to write custom magic, that gets --first or --second parameter, but raises an error, when there is no parameters at all. In simple argparse I can do this with mutually_exclusive_group, however I do not know, how to apply this in the case of Magics. Hardcoded example:

```
from IPython.core import magic_arguments
from IPython.core.magic import cell_magic, Magics, magics_class

@magics_class
class TestMagics(Magics):
    @cell_magic
    @magic_arguments.magic_arguments()
    @magic_arguments.argument('--first', '-f',
          action='store_true',
          help='Whether to print the results'
    )
    @magic_arguments.argument('--second', '-s',
          action='store_true',
          help='Whether to print the results'
    )
    def hello(self, line='', cell=None):
        args = magic_arguments.parse_argstring(self.hello, line)
        if args.first or args.second:
            print('hello ' + cell)
        else:
            print('error should occur!')

ip = get_ipython()
ip.register_magics(TestMagics)
```

In chunk:

```
%%hello 
world
```

should raise an error